# Dynamically adding textbox on button click in ASP .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm follow this code from youtube, but this code not work for me..

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    </div>        
    </form> </body>
```

here the code behind

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Web;
  using System.Web.UI;
  using System.Web.UI.WebControls;


 namespace WebApplication4
{
 public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    List<string> controlIdList = new List<string>();
    int counter = 0;
    protected override void LoadViewState(object savedState)
    {
        base.LoadViewState(savedState);   
        
        controlIdList = (List<string>)ViewState["contrloIdList"];
        foreach (string Id in controlIdList)
        {
            counter++;
            TextBox tb = new TextBox();
            tb.ID = Id;
            LiteralControl lineBreak = new LiteralControl();
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(tb);
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(lineBreak);
        }
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        counter++;
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        tb.ID = "textbox" + counter;
        tb.Text = "new textbox";

        LiteralControl lineBreak = new LiteralControl("<br />");
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(tb);
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(lineBreak);
        controlIdList.Add(tb.ID);
        ViewState["controlIdList"] = controlIdList;
    }
}}
```

the error is

> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
> the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
> information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference
> not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Line 17:
>
> Line 18:             controlIdList =(List)ViewState["contrloIdList"];
> Blockquote
>
> Line 19:             foreach (string Id in controlIdList)
>
> Line 20:             {
>
> Line 21:                 counter++;

Comment: `object savedState` It didnt get any values..Did u pass any values while calling the **LoadViewState**

Comment: You have misspelled ViewState["contrloIdList"] in **LoadViewState** method. Look closely you too will notice the same therefore you are getting **NullReferenceException**. You need to set controlIdList not contrloIdList.

Comment: the best way to add textbox in button click is use jquery or javascript, write your onclick function in javascript and simple you can add a text box inside that click event

Comment: I would suggest to use a repeater to dynamically add textbox.